# keyboard gets stuck on endEditing/resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios

Just noticed this really weird thing (iOS 5.1, sim and device):

I have a fairly straightforward UITableViewController. It's in edit mode with some lightly-customized UITextFields. Touch in a cell and it becomes first responder, keyboard pops up, all fine. I have a couple of different controls (e.g., your typical keyboard toolbar) that force the keyboard to hide by resigning the first responder. Normally this all works fine.

Except when the view that is the first responder is not on screen when the control is touched.  It does resign first responder, seen both by tracing the call and scrolling back up and seeing that it no longer has focus/cursor. But the keyboard doesn't hide. In fact, from that point on, it often never happens, even when I pop the controller.

Code's a little much to quote. But I've gone so far as to track down (via the view hierarchy starting from the window) the first responder before and after the resign call and it's what I expect, the text field prior, nothing afterwards. But the damn keyboard's still there.

Anyone seen this before? Anything obvious? Or not obvious?

Update: I did find a workaround, which is to create an trivial UITextField, add it to the view, become and resign first responder on it, and remove it from the view. Seems like a hack and I wonder how it will play with other versions, but unless there's a right way to do it ...

Makes me guess that it's a bug in UITableViewController (or possibly UITableView, but to me the controller is more suspect.)